# Is GraphQL supported in flutter web

Tags: flutter, web, graphql

I'm starting to develop web app using flutter web and graphql (https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter)

when trying to initialize the graphql I got this error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type '_Future<String>'
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (errors.dart:195)
    at Object.castError (errors.dart:44)
    at Object.cast [as as] (operations.dart:406)
```

Comment: can you post the intialization code?

Answer (score 2):

I just tried it, using flutter with simple graphql code from this https://github.com/CoderJava/flutter-graphql-sample.
And so far it works for flutter web (Flutter 1.24.0-10.2.pre • channel beta & graphql: ^3.1.0):

[image]

Comment: great, will try it

Comment: Hi @kira, so how's your experience so far? I was thinking of integrating GQ in my flutter app, and I need web support as well.

Comment: On my current project using flutter web, we use both rest API for update, and graphql for retrive data. so far there is no issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it's compatible with Flutter web.
[image: pub dev screenshot]

the package states that it supports Android and iOS.

Comment: so there is no library supported for the web I guess